# Quasar SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, quasar-framework

I have installed `quasar cli` following the [official website](https://quasar.dev/start/quasar-cli). I have created a test project using `yarn create quasar` command. Once I executed the the command `quasar dev` and it successfully executed a server and I can open it in. browser.

But subsequently whenever I use the `quasar` command in the terminal I get the following error

```
~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js:1
export default function ansiRegex({onlyFirst = false} = {}) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sudiptaroy/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js:2:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

The command is not working at all for some reason. May be I have installed some unmet dependencies while experimenting, I am not sure. I am very new to this. Can someone help?

My node version is `v16.13.0`, yarn version `1.22.19`, npm is at `8.1.0`.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running it in the terminal? Looks like strip-ansi is an ES module so you will need to trigger nodes support for ES modules either via `type: "module"` in package.json or by using a file with `.mjs` extension to kick-off your CLI process. You do not want the CJS loader in the stack, for example this `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader`.

Comment: I am just running `quasar` command in the terminal. Earlier it gave valid output. But all of a sudden it started giving the error.